# Issues packing LWJGL 3 project into executable .jar file

Tags: java, lwjgl, jarsplice

I'm having issues exporting my java project written with the LWJGL library (version 3.2.1) because of the new bundling of the native ('.dll') files.

I want to run my code outside of eclipse to test the speed it which my game runs, but there seems to be no simple way of exporting a project with references to external libraries.

When I open jarSplice (right after I export my project as a (not runnable) '.jar' file), I add the jars of LWJGL (which are grouped into sets of ['XX.jar', 'XX-natives-windows.jar'] and skip the natives section (because LWJGL apparently handles that on its own now) and press "Create FAT file". Then I receive following message: "Error: Duplicate file [whatever the first native file name was].dll".

I've heard of using  `System.setProperty()` but I don't understand how to utilize that properly.

If anyone knows how to do this please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Edit: I'm sorry if this is slightly off-topic but I haven't found a better site to ask this

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could explain what the class path is in this example and what the root of it is.

Comment: So in the case of C:/xxx/.../projectName.jar the native jars have to be located in a direct subfolder of the jar or next to it?

Comment: That's exactly my issue though. I need the natives as .dll files but mine only come as .jars

Comment: Oh I didn't know. I'm using Eclipse so it's probably possible. I'll try that solution. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I'm sorry but I've try doing this all day now and haven't managed. If you could lay out a detailed answer including all the steps from having a project with a library with regular jars as well as native jars(windows if I forgot to add) to having a jar file + a file of jars(which I already have) + a file of natives(or just have them located somewhere in .dll form) so I can put that information into jarSplice. I'd greatly appreciate it!